# Use relative path for svg in Angular Library Component

Tags: angular, svg, angular-library, ng-packagr

I created a custom Library with Angular Cli. It has the following structure:

```
 - dist
 - projects 
    - customLib
        - src
            - assets
                - icons
            - lib
                - button
```

The button component gets as Input() the name of the svg icon that will be displayed inside the button:

```
  import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'lib-button',
templateUrl: './button.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./button.component.scss']
 })

export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
svgIconUrl: string;

constructor() {
}

ngOnInit() {
  if (this.icon) {
    this.svgIconUrl = '../../assets/icons/' + this.icon + '.svg';
  }
}}
```

html of button component:

```
<button>
   <div *ngIf="svgIconUrl">
    <svg-icon [src]="svgIconUrl"></svg-icon>
   </div>
</button>
```

I made a script which copy all icons (stored in src/assets/icons) and paste it inside dist folder. All this is working fine. Then, I published my library on bitbucket and I installed it in another Angular Application.
The Library is imported correctly, but angular-svg-icon cannot find the svg because it is taking the svg in localhost:4200/#/assets/icons/myicon.svg

And of course it doesn't find the svg, because it is inside the library, so it is inside the "node_modules" folder. How can i force the button component of Library to take the svg inside the Library, so with a relative path?

this is the html, in the Angular App (which is importing and using the Library) where I use the button:

```
    <lib-button icon="icon-magic"></lib-button>
```

Comment: Hi, found the answer, I wonder? Having the same kinda issue; I mean, well, additional script for library PostInstall could probably be created (to copy again from ng-package.json allocated 'assets' clause to some servable location on user's point, who installs your lib); or I use just base64 strings -- all to much hassle; hence I wonder is there better soluting

Comment: Hi, no, I didn't find the answer :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've faced the same problem, and the only decision I've found is to include to `ng-package.json` in "lib" section "cssUrl"  param:

```
"lib": {
   "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts",
   "cssUrl": "inline"
 },
```

According docs, it allows embed assets in css file using data URIs.